# How to modify testNG report in selenium java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, java, testng

I am running my script in java and getting the results in testNG. But in my application after filling up the form I am getting a confirmation alert message. I am able to read that alert message and capture screenshot using selenium but I want to write/include that alert message and screenshot (or its path) in the testNG report.

Is there any way to do that as I am new to testNG

Comment: Look into this site once (But not TestNG) - http://automationtestingutilities.blogspot.in/p/reporting.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use reportNG. Its the reporting plugin for testNG. You can add your message using
Reporter.log("Your Message");

If you want to add your alert messages in report and your project is Maven project then add following in pom.xml

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.testng.xslt</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng-xslt-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <showRuntimeTotals>true</showRuntimeTotals>
                <sortTestCaseLinks>true</sortTestCaseLinks>
                <testDetailsFilter>FAIL,PASS,SKIP,CONF</testDetailsFilter>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Using Reporter.log("Your message"); you can add your messages and can see in Test Output-> index.html ->Reporter Output

For more details http://seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/configuring-reportng-with-testng-to-generate-html-reports